# jsdoc typedef with limited scope

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, typedef, jsdoc

### Background

I am using jsdoc in a project with PhpStorm. The goal is to allow the IDE to do static type checking.

I assume that the IDE developers attempt to follow and implement the conventions and meanings put forward by the jsdoc project itself.

I also assume that the logic for jsdoc in PhpStorm is the same as in WebStorm.

In general, types defined with `@typedef` apply in all files and scopes of the project - at least this is how it is implemented in PhpStorm. This forces deep namespacing to distinguish those types, which can be quite annoying sometimes.

### Question

In some cases I want to declare types with `@typedef` that only apply to a specific file. Is there a syntax for this in jsdoc?

### Example

E.g. I have a bunch of files each defining a specific d3 graph, with a specific format / structure for data records, coming from a csv file.

At the top of each file, I want to put a typedef to document the properties of a record, which is specific to this graph.

I then want to use this typedef to document function parameters further down in the file.

Comment: there is no way to do this in JSDoc